# How to create service in iOS?

Tags: iphone, rest, ios7, xcode5

Does any one suggest to how make a background service in iOS(iPhone/iPad) app?

Is it possible the service running at background continuously?
I have to make service with HTTP communication(REST service).Which can help to launch other application.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to establish Asynchronous Connection which works on behind the application while Synchronous connection works on Main thread which is not your requirements.

You can Download ASIHTTP classes from Github to implement while

You can found good description about these files from [Here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and Implementation example is [Here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: ASIHTTP is a bit old and as far as I know not supported instead AFNetworking is more on the top now